# What are uv and v8 in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, v8, libuv

There are 2 directories **uv** and **v8** in **deps** folder

First question : what is the definition of deps directory?

My second question: What are uv and v8 utilities in Node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a bit more detail:

**libuv** is a library for asynchronous I/O, originally developed for Node.js, and by now also used by a number of other projects. See https://github.com/libuv/libuv.

**V8** is the JavaScript engine that powers Google Chrome, other Chromium-derived browsers (Opera, Yandex Browser, the Android versions of Firefox Focus and Microsoft Edge, and a bunch of others), CEF-derived desktop software (GitHub's Atom, Microsoft's Visual Studio Code, Valve's Steam, and others), Node.js, and many other embedding applications. See https://developers.google.com/v8/.

Answer (score 2):

deps or dependencies: that contains things that are built outside of nodejs but are a part of node js.

UV and V8 are C++ dependencies for node JS